# code in constructor in java is called only once even page refreshed

Tags: java, jsf

is it possible in java that code in constructor is called only once even if page is refreshed via some actionListener. In C# Page.PostBack method works fine but here in java i can not find right method.

Comment: What "pages" are you talking about? A Java constructor will only be called once - per instance. if your constructor code gets called more than you expect, you probably create more objects than you expected to.

Comment: jsf page. Every refresh call default constructor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can know when it's postback with a function such as:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class HelperBean {

     public boolean isPostback() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            return context.getRenderKit().getResponseStateManager().isPostback(context);
        }

}
```

If for every refresh the default constructor is called, that means that your bean is `RequestScoped`. A refresh (GET) or a postback (POST) are considered as requests, so the bean will be created for every request. There are other instantiation options such as `SessionScoped` or `ApplicationScoped` or just instantiate it when a **postback** occurs, with the above function.

Setting the scope a-la-JSF1.2

Edit your `faces-config.xml` file located under `/WEB-INF`:

```
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.mypackage.myBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

you can use `request`, `session` or `application`

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about JSF then you need to change your BackingBeans scope from "Application" or "Session" to "Request".

This way your constructor works per request.

Example for JSF 2.0:

```
@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped
public class MyBackingBean {
  ...
}

@ManagedBean()
@RequestScoped
public class MyBackingBean {
  ...
}
```